# I could not finish a watson studio setup , I keep getting error messages "can not read property 'language_info' undefined

Tags: ibm-watson

I was trying to set up a watson studio , but I keep getting error message that says 'can not read property 'language_info' undefined'

Comment: Please refer  [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for a course project. No one else has seemed to encounter it.

I changed the URL I was using to http from https and it worked. This could be the solution, or I just needed to back up and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

In case it saves someone a bit of time:

I ran into the same issue in the Assignment 2 of the class "Fundamentals of Scalable Data Science". The reason is that the URL we had to import as Notebook is not the first one that appears in the instructions, as it was in Assignment 1. The URL to be imported was lower on the page.

Long story short: **You may be importing the wrong URL**.